# Best practice to connect two monitors with my Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

currently i am asking which is the best practice to connect two HDMI monitors on my Macbook Pro. I have on HDMI slot and one Display Port. It is possible to chain the monitors via one display port or i have to connect one via hdmi and one via the mini display port?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thunderbolt can chain, everything else needs one monitor per port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find DisplayPort to HDMI adaptor and connect one monitor over it and another one over HDMI.

Besides I wonder how exactly you gonna chain two HDMI monitors?

Comment: It is not possible to chain two HDMI monitors via one HDMI adapter, only with DisplayPort this is possible. I have solve it with your solution. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use this DisplayPort to HDMI on my Mac Book Air (for $ 6)

Mini DisplayPort to HDMI® Adapter w/ Audio Support

http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=104&cp_id=10428&cs_id=1042802&p_id=5311&seq=1&format=1

and it works like a charm!

PS
I do not think the daisy chain will work.